# How react lifecycle componentDidUpdate works click event

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    isLoading: true,
    users: [],
    error: null,
    showItems: 3
  };


  fetchUsers() {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data =>
        this.setState({
          users: data,
          isLoading: false,
        })
      )
      .catch(error => this.setState({ error, isLoading: false }));
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      showItems: 
          this.state.showItems >= this.state.users.length ?
            this.state.showItems : this.state.showItems + 1
      })
    }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.handleClick();
  } 

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchUsers();
  }
  render() {
    const { isLoading, users, error } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h1>Random User</h1>
        {error ? <p>{error.message}</p> : null}
        {!isLoading ? (
          this.state.users.slice(0, this.state.showItems).map(user => {
            const { username, name, email } = user;
            return (
              <div key={username}>
                <p>Name: {name}</p>
                <p>Email Address: {email}</p>
                <hr />
              </div>
            );
          })
        ) : (
          <h3>Loading...</h3>
        )}

        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Add more</button>

      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

How to load data on click event one by one using componentDidUpdate life cycle hook Reactjs, Fetching data is working fine but updating on click mess up

I tried this way don't understand how this would be a better solution. please guide

Also, explain did it really need componentDidUpdate here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where is `handleClick()` and what it does?

Comment: Sorry updated the question please have a look

Comment: My concern is by default it should display two items when i click it gets me more item one by one as per click triggered

Comment: What do you mean by `updating on click mess up`?

Comment: It loads everything before click that what i meant

Comment: You are not binding `handleClick` function. Use arrow function(`handleClick = () => {}`) or bind the function in constructor.

Comment: @Viru45 What is initial length of `users` array in state? means after fetching data from api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, calling `this.handleClick` in `componentDidUpdate` will increment `this.state.showItems` infinitely. You need to call `this.handleClick` only on `onClick` of `Add more` button.

**`ComponentDidUpdate` is invoked immediately after updating occurs.**

On click of `Add More` button, `showItems` is incremented in `state`. This will trigger `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle method.

`ComponentDidUpdate` again calls `this.handleClick`. Now `this.handleClick` will update `showItems` in state which will once again trigger `ComponentDidUpdate`. This loop will run infinitely.

So, remove `this.handleClick` from `componentDidUpdate`.

You don't need componentDidUpdate.

Also, you need to bind `handleClick`. Change declaration of handleClick to `handleClick = () => {...}` or add following in constructor: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)`

React doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

Comment: I removed this from componentDidUpdate still does not work click event nothing working

Comment: As like hooks does check the dependacies if something change found it allow to update the user that's what i'm looking for

Comment: You are not binding `handleClick` function. Use arrow function(`handleClick = () => {}`) or bind the function in constructor.

Comment: @tarzenchugh Yupp... forgot to notice it :)